# How to show pictures when users click each button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show different images when users click different buttons. But this code doesn't work

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    $(`#btn-${i}`).on("click", function (event) {
        num = i;
        if (i === 1) {
            $("#pre").attr("disabled", "disabled") 
        }
        else {
            $("#pre").removeAttr("disabled") 
        }
        for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
            if (i === j) {
                $(`#img-${j}`).css("display", "inline-block"); // show the image corresponding with the button
            }
            else {
                $(`#img-${j}`).css("display", "none"); // hide other images
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code doesn't work is because the entire for loop executes, making the value of the variable `i` become 5 at the very end. Then, when the on click event executes, it thinks of `i` as 5, and not the number you actually want it to be. The solution to that is instead of using `i` within the callback function, use `this.id.split("-")[1];`, gets the id of the button you clicked, and gets the image number from there.

You can see the code working in the snippet below (I used a `<div>` tag to replicate your images, just replace the divs with your images)

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  $(`#btn-${i}`).on("click", function(event) {
    var num = this.id.split("-")[1];
    if (num == 1) {
      $("#pre").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    } else {
      $("#pre").removeAttr("disabled")
    }
    for (var j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
      if (num == j) {
        $(`#img-${j}`).css("display", "inline-block"); // show the image corresponding with the button
      } else {
        $(`#img-${j}`).css("display", "none"); // hide other images
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-1">Button 1</button>
<button id="btn-2">Button 2</button>
<button id="btn-3">Button 3</button>
<button id="btn-4">Button 4</button>

<div id="img-1">Image 1</div>
<div id="img-2">Image 2</div>
<div id="img-3">Image 3</div>
<div id="img-4">Image 4</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I only need to remove the var, since I have a global var num above already